# How to get a username when logging in to Fat-Free Framework?

Tags: php, authorization, fat-free-framework

I use a fat-free framework, inside there is a plugin for authorization.

I connected it, everything works correctly https://fatfreeframework.com/3.7/auth
to enter the user name and password, I use the ready-made form of the framework, the `$auth->basic method();`
The method returns true or false.

```
$db = new \DB\SQL ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project1', 'root', 'topsecret123');
$user = new \DB\SQL\Mapper($db, 'users');
$auth = new \authorize ($user, array('userid identificator=>", 'PW'=>'password'));
$auth - >basic (); / / you will be prompted to log in to the network to authenticate the user
```

tell me how to get a username when logging in, this is important for the sites to work.

Comment: Does looking at a unit test help you out? https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/blob/dev/app/auth.php

Comment: Judging by the content of the authorization files, there is no get username function? Class properties are protected and cannot be accessed. Is it possible to somehow get the username using the callback function?

Comment: My only other guess would be to not use the framework but instead pull the global that they entered into the basic auth. Something like `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` https://www.devdungeon.com/content/http-basic-authentication-php#:~:text=%20HTTP%20Basic%20Authentication%20with%20PHP%20%201,If%20you%20are...%204%20References.%20%20More%20

Answer (score 0):

You can use this similar code.

```
function userAuth() {
    $f3 = \Base::instance();
    $mapper = new DB\SQL\Mapper($f3->DB, 'users_tbl');
    $auth = new \Auth($mapper, array('id' => 'email_mysql_col', 'pw' => 'password_mysqlcol'));
    
    //  if($auth->basic()) { // You can use callback, or just leave blank
    if($auth->basic('passwordAuth_callback')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function passwordAuth_callback($pw) {
    $f3 = \Base::instance();
    return md5($f3->SALT . $pw);
}
```